# SQLLDR Error: Object does not exist while trying to insert data to a database

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I am trying to upload data to a table using sql ldr-

```
sqlldr userid=aa2012/uaxiqdz@ADB control=simple.ctl
```

simple.ctl:-

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '../data/simple.csv'
BADFILE '../data/simple.bad'
DISCARDFILE '../data/simple.dsc'
INTO TABLE SIMPLE_TAB
replace
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(
  ID INTEGER 

EXTERNAL, 
  NAME CHAR(32)
)
```

simple.csv has two columns: 1st-number 2nd Name.

```
create table Simple_Tab (
  id    number primary key,
  name  varchar2(32)
)
```

But I get the following error -

> SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 -
>   Production on Sat Dec 4 22:43:55 2010
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All
>   rights reserved.
>
> SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe
>   of table SIMPLE_TAB ORA-04043: object
>   SIMPLE_TAB does not exist

I tried -

1. Carefully choosing the filepaths where i store the files.
2. Deleting and recreating the table SIMPLE_TAB
3. Carefully using upper case in all the commands

but none helped.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

You were probably connected to a different database (or user) when you ran the `create table` statement.

What does `select user from dual;` show you when run in SQL*Plus (e.g. right after/before running the `create table`)

Comment: I can see the table added on the left panel of the sqldeveloper. So I am pretty sure that the table is created.

Comment: And you are sure that SQLDeveloper connects to **exactly** the same database and user as your connection for SQL*Loader?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue today. In my case, it was that I *thought* the table name was `tblname`, when in fact, it was `"tblname"` (with quotes).

I also work with SQL Developer, and the Schema Browser showed that the table name was `tblname`, which fooled me. Only when I used the drag-and-drop utility to create a select command from this table, did I see the table name actually contained quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason for this could happen when you do not qualify the table name in the control file with the schema name.

So, if your table is in schema `scott` and your table name is not qualified by this, then Sqlldr will complain when you use a login user other than `scott`.